# Infinite loop in suspended component even with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook that wrap any async operation into a "suspense compatible" promise.

Basically, in order to interact with the suspense API, I "throw" the promise with some extended props (code inspired by [jotai's implementation](https://github.com/pmndrs/jotai/blob/94c1a20bc38ece90b75155571c71eb43e07303cd/src/react/useAtomValue.ts#L12-L41))

```js
function useSuspended<Value>(promise: PromiseForSuspense<Value>): Value {
  switch (promise.status) {
    case undefined:
      // extends the "naked" promise with our fields
      promise.status = "pending";
      promise.then(
        (value) => {
          promise.status = "ok";
          promise.value = value;
        },
        (error) => {
          promise.status = "error";
          promise.error = error;
        }
      );
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal -- Expected to interact with suspense
      throw promise;
    case "pending":
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal -- Expected to interact with suspense
      throw promise;
    case "ok":
      return promise.value as Value;
    case "error":
      throw promise.error;
  }
}
```

In my consuming component, because I expect render to occurs multiple times, I wrap my async operation into a `useMemo` call since my async operation needs parameters from props:

```js
const SomeComponent: React.FC<{ val: number }> = ({ val }) => {
  const computed = useSuspended(
    useMemo(() => {
      return asyncCompute(val);
    }, [val])
  );

  return <p>{computed}</p>;
};
```

However, even thought I use `useMemo`, this setup create an infinite loop. My `asyncCompute` is triggered on every render.

How can I fix that ?

Full repro (in [in codesandbox too](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hugle-osp6z9?file=/src/App.tsx)):

```js
import React, { Suspense, useMemo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type PromiseForSuspense<T> = Promise<T> & {
  status?: "pending" | "ok" | "error";
  value?: T;
  error?: unknown;
};

function useSuspended<Value>(promise: PromiseForSuspense<Value>): Value {
  switch (promise.status) {
    case undefined:
      // extends the "naked" promise with our fields
      promise.status = "pending";
      promise.then(
        (value) => {
          promise.status = "ok";
          promise.value = value;
        },
        (error) => {
          promise.status = "error";
          promise.error = error;
        }
      );
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal -- Expected to interact with suspense
      throw promise;
    case "pending":
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal -- Expected to interact with suspense
      throw promise;
    case "ok":
      return promise.value as Value;
    case "error":
      throw promise.error;
  }
}

const asyncCompute = async (val: number): Promise<number> => {
  console.log("Performing heavy computation");
  await new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, 2000)); // debug purpose
  return val * 2;
};

const SomeComponent: React.FC<{ val: number }> = ({ val }) => {
  const computed = useSuspended(
    useMemo(() => {
      return asyncCompute(val);
    }, [val])
  );

  return <p>{computed}</p>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Computing</p>}>
        <SomeComponent val={4} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**[Edit]** As a workaround, I discovered that moving the creation of the promise out of the suspended scope solve the issue:

```js
const SomeComponent: React.FC<{ val: number }> = ({ val }) => {
  const asyncOperation = useMemo(() => {
    return asyncCompute(val);
  }, [val]);

  const Inner = () => {
    const computed = useSuspended(asyncOperation);
    return <>{computed}</>;
  };

  return (
    <p>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Computing</p>}>
        <Inner />
      </Suspense>
    </p>
  );
};
```

This way the promise is created once in the parent component.

In term of react, this is working, however, it require to add a bunch of extra code in each component that use this technik. It also require setting inner Suspense, which is not always desired.